# Aside from binning in geom_histogram, I learned another way you can categorize continuous variable on the x-axis but cannot find online

Tags: r, ggplot2, bin

I recall learning online I believe three options for binning continuous variables as discrete but cannot locate it anymore. Basically, I have an x scale of 1 through 60 (seconds) but because there are so many, my sample size is small for each number. I'd like to bin it into six diff groups of ten (1:9 Seconds, 10-19 Seconds, etc.) - so more samples provide a better average (y-column)

I put some code below to show my basic starting point.

```
ggplot(data, aes(Seconds, Percentage))+
  geom_histogram()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:60)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to specify `geom_histogram(binwidth = 10)`. But this doesn't give you so much fine control; I think the bins will start with the minimum value, and won't necessarily be aligned to 1-10, 11-19, etc.

```
set.seed(0)
data = data.frame(Seconds = rnorm(1000, mean = 30, sd = 9))
range(data$Seconds)

ggplot(data, aes(Seconds))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10)
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:60)
```

[image]

Another option is to do it yourself, and count how many observations in each bin. `floor(your_var/binsize)*binsize` is a nice way to get bins like you describe.

```
library(dplyr)
binsize = 10
data %>%
  count(bin = floor(Seconds/binsize)*binsize) %>%
  ggplot(aes(bin + binsize/2, n)) + geom_col()
```

[image]